# How to create a new button by pressing a button in popup (python kivy)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to make a app. On button click on the bottom right of the screen there appears a dialog window(popup). I want to create a new button at the main screen on "Done" click.

I believed that the button would appear as on "Done" click "close_dialog" method is called, and this method calls "new_window" method afterwards. Could you please tell me why the code doesn't work and how to fix it. Thanks.

Code .py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

Window.size = (240, 426)

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Container(BoxLayout):
    dialog = None
    button_amount = 1

    def show_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Create new group",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
            )
        self.dialog.open()

    def close_dialog(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.new_window()

    def new_window(self, *args):
        self.add_widget(
        MDFlatButton(text="New group", size_hint_y=None, height=100))


class testApp(MDApp, Container):
    def build(self):
        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```

Code .kv:

```
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDCheckbox:
        hint_text: "Online"
        size_hint: (None, None)
        active: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Group name"

    MDFlatButton:
        id: btn1
        text: "Done"
        text_color: self.theme_cls.primary_color
        on_release: app.close_dialog()

<Container>
    orientation: "vertical"
    Screen:
        MDFloatingActionButton:
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.95, 'y': 0.05}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            on_release:
                app.show_dialog()

        NavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        MDToolbar:
                            size_hint: 1, 0.15
                            title: "Navigation Drawer"
                            elevation: 10
                            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                        Widget:

            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer

                ContentNavigationDrawer:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the button `Done` it's not beeing clicked because the `dialog` is auto dismissing before you can click it. So change your dialog to:

```py
self.dialog = MDDialog(
    title="Create new group",
    type="custom",
    content_cls=Content(),
    auto_dismiss=False
)
```

Then you need to tell your app where you want to insert the widget. Currently you are trying to put it on the App class and it won't work. In this example I put it in the main window, but you can change according to where you want:

```py
def new_window(self, *args):
    btn = MDFlatButton(text="New group", size_hint_y=None, height=100)
    self.root.add_widget(btn)
```